# Setting up a Test Bed in Ionic Provider

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I am really new into Ionic and Unit Testing. Current version is 3.12.0. I am using Karma and Jasmine for unit testing.

I have a provider called **test-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the TestServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class TestServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello TestServiceProvider Provider');
  }

}
```

Then I have a test spec in the same folder as follows contains a simple test with a test bed.

```
import { TestServiceProvider } from './test-service';
import { TestBed, TestModuleMetadata, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('Test Service', () => {
  let component: TestServiceProvider;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestServiceProvider>;

  beforeEach(async( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TestServiceProvider]
    }).compileComponents;
  }));

  beforeEach( () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestServiceProvider);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should add numbers', () => {
    expect(1+1).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

But when I run `npm test` it gives me an error

```
Unexpected value 'TestServiceProvider' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

TestServiceProvider must be in the declaration not in Imports

Change Your code as below :

```
beforeEach(async( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestServiceProvider]
    }).compileComponents;
  }));
```

Comment: I used the above code and now gives an error `Unexpected value 'TestServiceProvider' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`